# Add a BR tag to every empty line in output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formatting, pre

I've made a script which replaces characters, you input text into a text area and the output is put into a  tag (to keep all line breaks etc). (this is done using the replace method)

Im trying to figure out a way (Using javascript) to insert a 
 tag in each empty line in the  output, is this possible to do?

Comment: You should show the script that you already created, and possibly provide a fiddle example.

Comment: FYI, for line-breaks you can use `\n`.

Comment: You can do this: your_var.replace("\n","<br/>")

Comment: Can u specify more details of your requirement. can you explain what the tag meant ?

Comment: Which tag? What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: New lines are already kept in place due to the output being in pre tags. Will i be able to keep formatting and replace the new line breaks with br tags?

Comment: Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/zGLN7/ ???

Comment: That fiddle didnt work :(

Comment: @Namenone Which browser and OS??? It works for me on chrome win7. Of course, you need to write some text in textarea with empty lines and then click button. BTW, "That fiddle didnt work" is not enough to determine what's going wrong. At least make some effort to describe what means not working, thank you...

Comment: I'm trying to add two <bro

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using a library like http://ckeditor.com/.  It is highly configurable and accomplishes much of what you might want to do with editing.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible on the front end, this may be too much :(